# I keep being asked for an Administrator password in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, administrator, recovery

I'm on ubuntu 23.04 and I keep being asked for an Administrator password (not a root, Administrator). I don't have it... I never set it, and it's not the root password. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the context in which you are being asked for this password? Is it regardless what you are doing, or when you perform a specific action, or when you do a certain kind or type of action? What is the full message you receive when you get this prompt?

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Ubuntu install, the first user created *is* the Administrator. Have you tried just entering the password you set for that 'normal' user?

Comment: Please don't use the answers field for comments asking for clarification. You'll need at least 50 reputation points so I upvoted your other correct answers to give you a boost.

Comment: Sorry. I did think that it would be better to ascertain whether the OP had tried the normal password in a comment first, but then realised that I didn't have enough rep to do that. Should I delete my answer (even though it might provide the correct solution to the OP's problem)? And thanks for the upvotes!